# How to consume this api

Tags: jquery, ajax

I try to consume this api (https://ministerio.herokuapp.com) with `jQuery` , when I run the script the result is a blank html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>JavaScript - read JSON from URL</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="mypanel"></div>

    <script>
      $.getJSON('https://ministerio.herokuapp.com', function(data) {     
        var text = `Indexers: ${data.Indexers}`
        $(".mypanel").html(data);
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A quick look at the [**console**](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers/77337#77337) would have told your why it doesn't work. The error is `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: No Louys , i fix that error  , now the html file show a empty page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first had a `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` error when requesting the json ressource.

Congratulations, you fixed the header of the ressource.
It wasn't clear you had control over it at first.

Now, that resource isn't outputing a json yet.
The next error you will have to manage is `parsererror`.

### How did I found that error?

I used the `.fail()` callback.
See in [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/PJGwRZ?editors=1011)

```
$.getJSON('https://ministerio.herokuapp.com', function(data) {     
  // Whatever you do here in case of success.

}).fail(function(request,error){
  console.log(request);
  console.log(error);
});
```

You expect the result to be:

```
{"Ambiental":"1","Descripcion":"Mayormente nublado","Fecha_Actualizacion":"2017-09-21T18:09:51-05:00","Humedad":"70%","Picoyplaca":"1 - 3 - 5 - 7 - 9","Publico":"1 - 2","TasaRM":" $ 2,913.96","Temperatura":"14°"}
```

**But**, here is [what your ressource outputs](http://view-source:https://ministerio.herokuapp.com/) at the moment:

```
<p> {&quot;Ambiental&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;Descripcion&quot;:&quot;Mayormente nublado&quot;,&quot;Fecha_Actualizacion&quot;:&quot;2017-09-21T18:09:51-05:00&quot;,&quot;Humedad&quot;:&quot;70%&quot;,&quot;Picoyplaca&quot;:&quot;1 - 3 - 5 - 7 - 9&quot;,&quot;Publico&quot;:&quot;1 - 2&quot;,&quot;TasaRM&quot;:&quot; $ 2,913.96&quot;,&quot;Temperatura&quot;:&quot;14°&quot;}
```

---

**So...** Get rid of that unclosed `<p>`tag first.

*You should post that ressource code... As many weird things may be found there.*

But I'm quite sure the next step will be to just replace those [HTML entities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#HTML_character_references) by the real characters needed.

Then use `json_encode()` to echo the result to make sure it is properly formated if the data comes from an array *(I suppose that is a PHP script)*.

Comment: Hi louys , finally i correct the error , expressjs error sintax, but now is running without problem in this url http://rush-2049.herokuapp.com/ thanks